Problem with Implicit Component and Coupled components
I have a few questions on the strategy for my problem setup.
My problem is made of a group containing 5 key components, but 4 are instances of the same component (cable), which calculates the tension (its 3 components in 3D space) based on the deflections uvw (array(3)) at one end of the cable. The last component (balance) contains a nonlinear system of equations, which takes external loads as parameters, and the cable tensions as inputs; it outputs the deflections at a common point uvw_tip (array(3)), theta_tip, and the reactions XYZ0 (array(3)). A total of 7 output scalars.
The outputs uvw_tip and theta_tip are processed through an auxiliary component to calculate the uvw to input back into the cable components.
So I believe my balance component is an ImplicitComponent, yet the theta_tip does not even show up directly in the residual equations, because its effect is buried in the other inputs from the cable components (Nxyz_UC1..Nxyz_LC2, UC1_Bp..LC2_Bp). Thus, I think the solver returns a 'singular factor' for that 'column'.
There is also the coupling issue of connecting this to cable, and I am not sure of the best approach here, and not sure what I have setup so far is appropriate. If you could recommend a direction, I would appreciate it.
A related question is: in the ImplicitComponent I have 7 residual equations, but I am not interested in all the state variables, and only in the outputs mentioned above.
Am I handling correctly the uvw_tip and XYZ0 arrays in the residuals[xxx] below? Thank you in advance.
residuals['theta_legtip']  = L_L0**2 - ((L_L0  + uvw_legtip[0])**2 + uvw_legtip[1]**2 + uvw_legtip[2]**2)  #length of leg is invariant   ::Eq#1
residuals['XYZ0'][0] = Fxyz[0] + XYZ0[0] + Nxyz_UC1[0] + Nxyz_UC2[0] + Nxyz_LC1[0] + Nxyz_LC2[0] #Balance along X                ::Eq#2  
residuals['XYZ0'][1] = Fxyz[1] + XYZ0[1] + Nxyz_UC1[1] + Nxyz_UC2[1] + Nxyz_LC1[1] + Nxyz_LC2[1] #Balance along Y                ::Eq#3  
residuals['XYZ0'][2] = Fxyz[2] + XYZ0[2] + Nxyz_UC1[2] + Nxyz_UC2[2] + Nxyz_LC1[2] + Nxyz_LC2[2] - M_L*gravity #Balance along Z  ::Eq#4  
residuals['uvw_legtip'][0] = Mxyz[0] - L_L[2]*Fxyz[1] + (Fxyz[2] - M_L * gravity/2.) * L_L[1]          + \
                                                              UC1_Bp[1]*Nxyz_UC1[2] - UC1_Bp[2]*Nxyz_UC1[1] + \
                                                              UC2_Bp[1]*Nxyz_UC2[2] - UC2_Bp[2]*Nxyz_UC2[1] + \
                                                              LC1_Bp[1]*Nxyz_LC1[2] - LC1_Bp[2]*Nxyz_LC1[1] + \
                                                              LC2_Bp[1]*Nxyz_LC2[2] - LC2_Bp[2]*Nxyz_LC2[1]   #Eq.#5
residuals['uvw_tip'][1] = Mxyz[1] + L_L[1]*Fxyz[0] + (-Fxyz[2] + M_L * gravity/2.) * L_L[0]          + \
                                                              - UC1_Bp[0]*Nxyz_UC1[2] + UC1_Bp[2]*Nxyz_UC1[0]  \
                                                              - UC2_Bp[0]*Nxyz_UC2[2] + UC2_Bp[2]*Nxyz_UC2[0]  \
                                                              - LC1_Bp[0]*Nxyz_LC1[2] + LC1_Bp[2]*Nxyz_LC1[0]  \
                                                              - LC2_Bp[0]*Nxyz_LC2[2] + LC2_Bp[2]*Nxyz_LC2[0]  #Eq.#6
        
residuals['uvw_tip'][2] = Mxyz[2] + L_L[0]*Fxyz[1] - L_L[1]*Fxyz[0]                                  + \
                                                              - UC1_Bp[1]*Nxyz_UC1[0] + UC1_Bp[0]*Nxyz_UC1[1]  \
                                                              - UC2_Bp[1]*Nxyz_UC2[0] + UC2_Bp[0]*Nxyz_UC2[1]  \
                                                              - LC1_Bp[1]*Nxyz_LC1[0] + LC1_Bp[0]*Nxyz_LC1[1]  \
                                                              - LC2_Bp[1]*Nxyz_LC2[0] + LC2_Bp[0]*Nxyz_LC2[1]  #Eq.#7

To me it looks like the inputs of the independent component performing the solution of the system of equations do not update with the output of the other component. I also changed the order of the components because it seems like it had an effect, but in the end Nxyz_xx do not change inside the implicit component.
EDIT
I have changed the nonlinear_solver to be at the "cycle" level:
    cycle.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=False)
    cycle.nonlinear_solver.options['iprint'] = 3
    cycle.nonlinear_solver.options['maxiter'] = 20# 20
    self.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()

This alone gets rid of that singular factor matrix. I also reviewed in this forum (answer to an old question of mine  :)) that the nonlinear_sover will not use the outputs from other components at the first step. As a result, the residuals are way off to start with and have 0 hope of convergence. This is because the states are outputs from other components, and even with good guesses at the outputs, the residuals are off without good states. So how would you go about passing good states (outputs of the other components?)?
EDIT
I have used a workaround by using options to compute a better estimate of the guess to trickle down into the implicit component inputs. However, now I am facing this issue. One of the residual is large, because of the initial guess, the moment balance residual about the y-axis is not 0. The solver then assigns that large value of the residual to the argument of the residual, i.e. the residuals["uvw_tip"][2] -> uvw_tip[2],  which then will blow up any successive steps. Any recommendations here? Does this have to do with the lack of explicitly calculated derivatives in the explicit components?
EDIT

Thanks to Justin and Ken for your help. I managed to get the code to start working (prob.run_model), but I am not sure I have the solvers set up correctly, nonetheless, in non-optimization mode, I get a good solution of the system of equations. When I try the prob.run_driver(), I get the "Positive directional derivative for linesearch" error, and the optimization does not converge. The initial set of variables (obtained from the prob.run_model) should render a near optimum configuration, but the optimizer seems to get stuck in a space where the constraints cannot be satisfied. Could you please help me figure out how to overcome this new hurdle?
EDIT
I have tried different combinations, but I had first set: self.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=False) and self.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver() in the cycle group, which contains the implicit component. That returns some good results for some specific inputs when using COBYLA. For some other cases, it fails satisfying the constraints.  In the case of parallel cycle groups for multipoint optimization, the prob.run_model() would not return/compute the output of simple ExecComponents. This led me to inserting an additional solver at the outer level (bigger group): self.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=False) and self.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver().  This leads to the correct computation of prob.run_model(), but the optimization prob.run_driver() with either COBYLA or SLSQP  encounters a singular factor. Any direction or suggestion is appreciated.

There is not quite enough detail to fully answer your question. It would be best if you posted some runable code, even if its throwing a singular matrix error.
Abstractly, your model sounds similar to a nonlinear version of a truss solver, or a circuit solver. So you may want to look at this example to understand the interplay of explicit and implicit components better.
I would like to give more specific advice, but without some runalble code and the ability to see an N2 diagram its difficult.

HI Justin I am not sure how to attach the N2 or the code. I tried to edit the question with the code, but it is too long in its entirety. If you could help me figure out how to attach it, I would, though it might have some external classes that could be easily bypassed.

If you have a github account, you could just post your code there as a gist and link it here.

Thank you Ken, here is where code and N2 could be found https://github.com/rdamiani/SpiderFLOAT.git

I wasn't able to get your code to run because you seem to be using a different version of WISDEM rather than the public one. However, I did notice that none of your explicit components have partial derivatives defined. You definitely need derivatives for those, and that might be contributing to the singular error you are seeing. I would also recommend getting rid of the block GS solver in cycle, and moving the NewtonSolver and DirectSolver down into that group.

Also, the top NewtonSolver has a maxiter of 0.  Make sure to set it higher when you move it into cycle.

Yep, i have found out i needed to move the GS solver. I have posted the material class, which should be the only thing that was called under WISDEM (different from the public one), gravity is just a constant. The maxiter set to 0 was to understand whether i/os were passed properly among the various groups, which led me to the rediscovery that the first step does not use the outputs from other components.  question edited to clarify. Can I get away with auto-partial-derivatives just to get the code going, or do i have to define them necessarily. I thought they would primarily speed up the code.

I think it would be fine to just use complex step for those components while you are trying to build and debug your model. You can derive analytic derivatives later.

I have switched to COBYLA, and the linesearch problem went away. Still if you could take a look at my setup to see whether linear and nonlinear solvers are set as they should, I would appreciate it.

self.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver() --> This linear solve should be in cycle, not self.  The Newton solver needs the solver to function.

I think that was already done, so I am not sure whether there was a glitch in the git version you might have accessed. I had also used a NewtonSolver rather than GS, and unsure whether that is a good choice. However, I have now further expanded the model to have a multipoint optimization approach. It generally works, but for some reason I cannot get the output from the UC1LC1_mass (ExecComp) to show the actual value <>0. I am connecting a "sub" parallel subsystem outputs to its inputs, but I cannot get it to show with a get_val; what is going on here?

Could be that you don't know the right promoted name. Try doing a prob.model.list_vars() after your optimization, which will print all of the inputs and outputs in component execution order to stdout (which you redirect to a file). You should definitely get the value that way, and can see its promoted name that way too.

Thank you @Ken, It does not seem to have list_vars as a method (ver 3.27) but I use list_outputs, and that does not show anything unusual. I have another ExecComp that does a simple sum as well cable_totD, and that works, however, the connections are not with a parallel.sub system. The inputs of UC1LC1_mass are the correct ones from a get_val, however, so i am not clear as to why the output does not show up. The offending component is used in the objective function. I will continue investigating.

I should add that after a prob.run_driver the get_val('UC1LC1_mass.cables.mass') value is correct, but zero after a prob.run_model.

I edited the question a bit, but moving the ExecComp containing the objective output down past the cycle seemed to have helped as well with that output.
